# Spark Standalone Cluster on VMs

Tags: apache-spark, vagrant, virtual-machine, salt-stack

We’re looking at setting up a standalone Spark cluster (no need for Hadoop) for our R&D analytics and data mining project. 
To this end we are going to reserve a small number of pcs (4-8). For “political” reasons these machines all run Windows.
My question is if it’s possible to setup a Spark cluster across these pcs where each node runs on a Linux VM i.e. instead of having multiple VMs on a single pc, each node/pc would have its own VM running on it.
Note that operationally I’m quite new to Spark, my background being in databases. I’ve read about using Vagrant/Salt (new to these also) to provision the VMs but in most examples the starting point is a Linux based host and the VMs are all set up on a single machine.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think so. I've used Orable VM VirtualBox and Vagrant on my Windows OS PC to run a program written on my windows pc that can only run on Linux OS.

My guess is you would install Oracle VM VirtualBox with Linux or Ubuntu OS in each of these Window OS PCs, and then install Apache Spark on each node of Linux.